# Localization in Lumen

Tags: laravel, localization, lumen

Is there any clear documentation on Localization lumen? I searched the whole google/laracast to find some info/documentation about Localization  on Lumen but nothing so far.

I came a cross some documentation for lumen but it seems the recent version of lumen doesnt't support Localization .
How can I get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use preferredLocale in lumen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216880/how-to-use-preferredlocale-in-lumen)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/helpers.php:363` a `trans($id = null, $parameters = [], $domain = 'messages', $locale = null)`
function is defined, so you can use it in your views

If you don't request for a certain lang translation, it uses `dotenv`'s `APP_LOCALE` setting defined in your `.env` file to get the localized values.

Using Blade:

```
trans('file.key')
```

Using plain php:

```
<?php echo trans('file.key') ?>
```

Comment: Lumen does bootstrap the TranslationServiceProvider in the Application class, so yes, this should all work.

Comment: Thx for the help guys, fixed it :)

Comment: I am using Lumen 8.0 version, is there any one who can suggest me how can I use multiple local (English and French) in Lumen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be a good solution: [https://github.com/arispati/app-locale](https://github.com/arispati/app-locale)