# How to use preferredLocale in lumen?

Tags: laravel, notifications, lumen

With the release of Laravel 5.7 the Illuminate\Notifications\Notification class started offering a locale method to set the desired language. The application will change into this locale when the notification is being formatted and then revert back to the previous locale when formatting is complete. Here is an example of this feature:

```
$user->notify((new InvoicePaid($invoice))->locale('ar'));
```

I just need to use this feature in lumen (latest version) but when I implement that Like [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#localizing-mailables) said I got an error

`Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::getLocale()`
and this because there is no `getLocale` or `setLocale` methods in lumen application.. so any ideas to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difference between Lumen and Laravel is that in Laravel you call `Application->setLocale()`.

This does three things, as outlined above:

1. Set config `app.locale`
2. Set Locale on the translator
3. Fire the locale.changed event

**In Lumen** though, you would call the translator directly with `app('translator')->setLocale()` or `App::make('translator')->setLocale()`,

so the difference here is that the config variable will not be set automatically and the locale.changed event will not be fired.

Laravel's Application class also updates the config and fires an event:

```
public function setLocale($locale)
{
    $this['config']->set('app.locale', $locale);
    $this['translator']->setLocale($locale);
    $this['events']->fire('locale.changed', [$locale]);
}
```

and in Laravel, getLocale is just reading the config variable:

```
public function getLocale()
{
    return $this['config']->get('app.locale');
}
```

For translations thought, it's the translator that matters. Laravel's trans helper looks like this:

```
function trans($id = null, $parameters = [], $domain = 'messages', $locale = null)
{
    if (is_null($id)) {
        return app('translator');
    }
    return app('translator')->trans($id, $parameters, $domain, $locale);
}
```

**You need to make your application extends another class with the above 3 methods**

Answer (score 3):

You can Extend your `Laravel\Lumen\Application` in a new class and make `$app` variable take an instance from your new class in your `bootstrap\app.php` file

1- create the new class like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Core;

use Laravel\Lumen\Application as Core;

class Application extends Core
{
    /**
     * @param $locale
     */
    public function setLocale($locale): void
    {
        $this['config']->set('app.locale', $locale);
        $this['translator']->setLocale($locale);
        $this['events']->fire('locale.changed', [ $locale ]);
    }

    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this['config']->get('app.locale');
    }
}
```

2- make an instance from your new class ex:

`$app = new App\Core\Application(
    realpath(dirname(__DIR__) . '/')
);`